# PPTP VPN support IPv6 over IPv4

Tags: vpn, ipv6, pptp, point-to-point-protocol

My Server has both IPv4 and IPv6 and I've set up an PPTP VPN there. And my local network only supports IPv4. How can I gain IPv6 access by dialing in my VPN with IPv4? That means, is it possible to have a VPN which can forward IPv6 packets into IPv4?

Comment: PPTP can tunnel lots of protocols.  It pretty much lives at layer 2.  But since you have given zero information about what PPTP daemon or hardware you are using, it is unreasonable to believe anyone can tell you how.  Details vary based in implementation.

Comment: I'm using the common pptpd aka poptop server on CentOS.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/461795/126632

Answer (score 0):

Poptop does not support IPv6. This will not work. Sorry.